# Javascript OOP framework

Tags: javascript, oop, module, frameworks, mixins

I am wondering if the following code I have put together is the best way to define wrapper function for creating classes in js.

Does anyone have a better example willing to share as I thought of this as a first attempt.

What am I missing if anything?

```
j = {
    context : {}
};

j.namepsace = (function(){

    var createnamespace = function(parent, remainder){
        if(remainder.length === 0){
            return;
        }

        parent[remainder[0]] = parent[remainder[0]] || {};
        return createnamespace(parent[remainder[0]], remainder.splice(1));
    };

    return {
        define : function(ns){
            createnamespace(j.context, ns.split('.'));
        }
    }
}());

j.class = (function(){
    return {
        construct : function(namespace, name, ctor){
            namespace[name] = ctor;
        },
        ctor : function(namespace, name, ctor, prototype){
            for (var property in prototype) {
                if (prototype.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    ctor.prototype[property] = prototype[property];
                }
            }
            namespace[name] = ctor;
        }
    }
}());

j.mixin = (function(){
    return {
      with : function(object, objectliteral){
          for (var prototype in objectliteral) {
              if (objectliteral.hasOwnProperty(prototype)) {
                  object[prototype] = objectliteral[prototype];
              }
          }
      },
      toDefintion : function(classdefinition, mixin){
          var objectliteral =  mixin();
          for (var property in objectliteral) {
              if (objectliteral.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                  classdefinition.prototype[property] = objectliteral[property];
              }
          }
      }
    };
}());

j.namepsace.define('application.section');

j.class.construct(j.context.application.section,'printNameMixin', function(){
    return {
        printName : function(){
            console.log(this.name);
        }
    };
});

j.class.construct(j.context.application.section,'person',function(name, address, age){
    return {
        name : name,
        address : address,
        age : age
    };
});

j.class.ctor(j.context.application.section,'customer',function(name){
    this.name = name;
}, {
    name : 'unregistered client'
});

j.mixin.toDefintion(j.context.application.section.customer, j.context.application.section.printNameMixin );

var person = j.context.application.section.person('Blair Davidson','23 Test St',33);

var cust = new j.context.application.section.customer("Bankwest");
cust.printName();

console.log(person);
```

Comment: Bit open-ended is this...

Comment: seems like it results in a lot of dots, but if it works it's at least good.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is interesting but as you asked for what is wrong, I would note 3 things:

**1. Prototype**

With your method, you breaks the mechanism of the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) which is one of the power of javascript.

**2. Inheritance**

The mixin pattern is not my favorite pattern because it is often used to simulate multiple inheritance. But as the [Single Responsability Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and the fact that an inheritance should only be used to factorize code between classes having the same responsability suggest it, multiple inheritance should be avoided in a good OOP design.

**3. OOP**

If you want to do some strong OOP, you certainly need more features than that (like interfaces, dependency injection, ...). For this, I would suggest you to take a look at existing frameworks because it is a really long task (believe me). You can see an example of that kind of framework following the link in my profile (this is a javascript framework only working with nodejs but that you can use on both client (browser) and server (nodejs) side).